# How to replace fetch_all in this function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I need to replace fetch_all, because my hosting does not support it

Found the way to do it with a loop. But I could not.

Function

```
function getMenusuno()
{
   global $conex;
   $respuesta= mysqli_query ($conex, "SELECT M.menu_nombre, M.menu_ruta FROM privilegios P 
   INNER JOIN menus M ON P.menu_id = M.menu_id WHERE tipousu_id='".$_SESSION['resultipo']."' 
   AND M.menu_id BETWEEN '1' AND '4' ORDER BY p.menu_id ASC");
   $respuesta->fetch_all();
}
```

Try this loop. But not how to structure

```
   $data = [];
   while ($row = $respuesta->fetch_assoc()) {
     $data[] = $row;
   }
```

I put it in or out of the function?. Please help me

Comment: Your  code seems ok... $data should hold what you want. What is going wrong?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: I need to show the names of the menus that I keep in a database. He shows me two initial and two menus, not complete.

Comment: Your mixing `procedural` with `oop` you can't do that

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.8. in my host version 5.6

Comment: @cmorrisey how to do resolve it!!!??

Comment: Can you update your code to show how you are showing the data?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Eventually use the same while, I had to set it to my requirements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `fetch_all()`, first execute, than fetch row-wise: `index_columns` is a speciality of me ... ;)

```
$sql_result = $this->pdo_execute();
while ($row = $this->stmt->fetch()) {
    $data_array[$row[<index_column ... e.g. memberID>]] = $row;
}
```

Assuming `index_column` is e.g. `memberID`, you may access ANY member directly in the `$data_array`, if you know (and most times you do or should know) the `ID` like:

```
$data_array[<memberID>] = ARRAY(of member=<memberID> data); // coOl ;)
```

Comment: I'm gonna try it, results will comment =)

Comment: Eventually use the same while, I had to set it to my requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access your data using the $data array. Try testing it out:

```
foreach($data as $value){
   var_dump($value);
}
```

You'll be able to see that the array should give you named keys of 'menu_nombre' & 'menu_ruta' Try accessing like this:

```
// first row
$data[0]['menu_nombre'];
```

Comment: generates menu names entered me according to the users, in this function the query show menus between 1 and 4 (menus id)

Comment: Eventually use the same while, I had to set it to my requirements :)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the mysqli_fetch_assoc as complete for extract information of the query. Like:

```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($my_query) ) {
     echo $row['column_name1'];
     echo $row['column_name2'];
     echo $row['column_name3'];
     echo $row['column_name4'];
     echo $row['column_name5'];
 }
```

Note: `$my_query` is the variable where you save the mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table")

Comment: the column_name It is dynamically generated, I need the function to use in another page. like this $function1 = getMenusuno();